# Get an array instead of string

Tags: arrays, json, swift, string

After parsing my JSON I get the following value:

```
myArray = "[63, 83, 87, 71]"
```

How could I get an array instead of string? What I need is:

```
myArray = [63, 83, 87, 71]
```

Update:

Here is my simple json:

```
{
    "0": "[31,47,51]",
    "1": "[74, 47, 51, 78]",
    "2": "[72, 65, 69, 80]",
    "3": "[63, 83, 87, 71]"
}
```

Here is a parsing:

```
class gameModel: NSObject {
    func getCurrentArrays() -> NSDictionary {
        let appBundlePath:String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "testJsonPrepared", ofType: "json")

        if let actualBundlePath = appBundlePath {
            let urlPath:NSURL? = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: actualBundlePath)
            if let actualUrlPath = urlPath {
                let jsonData:NSData? = NSData(contentsOf: actualUrlPath as URL)
                if let actualJsonData = jsonData {
                    let dict: NSDictionary? = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: actualJsonData as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary?
                    if let currentArrays = dict {
                        return currentArrays
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return NSDictionary()
    }
}
```

Here is a final:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let model = gameModel()
    var arrays: NSDictionary = ["":""]

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        arrays = model.getCurrentArrays()
        print("# func viewDidLoad arrays: \(arrays)")

        let testKey = String(3)

        let testArray = arrays.value(forKey: testKey) as! String
        print("# func viewDidLoad testArray: \(testArray)")
    }
}
```

===========

Update2 Thanks, rmaddy. Here is my solution:

testJson.json

```
{
  "0": [31,47,51],
  "1": [74, 47, 51, 78],
  "2": [72, 65, 69, 80],
  "3": [63, 83, 87, 71]
 }
```

here is reading from json:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {



override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "testJson", ofType: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
            let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves)
            if let jsonResult = jsonResult as? Dictionary<String, [Int]>, let array = jsonResult["3"] {
                print("# func didMove array: \(array)")
            }
        } catch {
            // handle error
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: The backend is not correctly encoding the values. You will need to either ask your backend team to fix it, fix the backend yourself, or parse that array manually.

Comment: Yeah, you need to fix the JSON. The array of integers should not be a string in the JSON.

Comment: And unrelated but in Swift you should not use `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, `NSData`, `NSURL`, etc. Use a proper Swift dictionary and array. Use `Data`. Use `URL`. And you probably don't need to extend `NSObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Andy, array values is not encoded not in correct format hence is been decoded as string. Format should be as follows

```
{
    "0": [31,47,51],
    "1": [74, 47, 51, 78],
    "2": [72, 65, 69, 80],
    "3": [63, 83, 87, 71]
}
```

In case u are unable to fix json, following extension should do the trick

```
extension String{
    func toArray()->[Int]{
        var trimmedStr = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: "")
        trimmedStr = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "")
        let strArray = trimmedStr.components(separatedBy: ",")
        return strArray.flatMap({Int($0)})

    }
}
```

and use it on ur arrayString as follows

```
myArray = myArrayString.toArray()
```

Comment: It works, too. 1000thanks. Now I also solved it in the way suggested by rmaddy.

Comment: Instead of processing the string manually, the array string is itself valid JSON. Just parse it like you would normal JSON.